# unable to add tomcat on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat7

I try to add tomcat on eclipse I made window ---> preferences ---> servers-----> runtime environments then I click  add. But I can't find tomcat in the list of server.
I get like in the picture. When I made some research I find that I should use version of eclipse greater then 3.7. I use eclipse 3.8 and apache-tomcat-7.0.34.
Any one can help me what can be the problem or there is another configuration?[image]

Comment: You might want to consider installing 3.7 (JEE Profile), or 4.2.

Comment: Please send me the link to install eclipse that can configure Tomcat

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When I install Eclipse Helios I can get the list of server.
The problem is solved